# setting up react native code repository for Mac & Windows

Tags: react-native, repository

I want to setup a local repository for react native projects since I cannot use Git because of privacy issue.

Pls suggest what software can be used to setup local code repository on windows server and I can commit from MAC or windows.

I am using tortoise SVN for other projects but it does not support MAC OS.

Comment: Could you elaborate the privacy issue with git? It is possible to have a local git repository only. Also a self-hosted software/server or using a cloud provider within certain legal spheres.

Comment: It is not related to Git but the standard policy related to banking sector for that particular client does not allow to setup Git repositories.

Answer (score 1):

[Subversion from Apache](http://subversion.apache.org/) as CLI Tool is available on the Mac by default. You might use that. Even though tortoise svn is not available on the Mac there are multiple clients to choose from that support the svn protocol.